# How can i manage bandwidht in linux router or firewall?

Tags: linux, firewall

I have Linux  server for internet sharing . i have 6 Mbps bandwidth,  Now i want set 30Kbit to 40Kbit per 
user bandwidth. I want  configure without proxy. It is possible that tc configration will help me for set the limit for per user?

Regards

Nandan

Comment: No - because tc doesn't know what a "user" is - but you can limit bandwidth to/from designated IP addresses.

Comment: to symcbean: maybe you can limit per user with the uid matching and marking pcakets based on uids. TC can then shape traffic based on the mark.

Comment: to Endre Szabo:-  If i have eth0 :172.71.23.1( internet)   and eth1: 192.168.2.1 ( local) internet users, i have 254 different ip address for users.  Then how can i set uid for per ip or  users.